# Summary statistics on attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, attribute-table

I've got a polygon feature class with attributes fields
`y2010`, `y2011`, `y2012`, `y2013`, `y2014`, `country`

The 'year' fields contain counts of an event occurrence, which can be 0 or > 0. The 'country' field' is an identifier for country A or B, so the table looks like this:

```
y2010 | y2011 | y2012 | y2013 | y2014 | country

   0  |  10    |   1   |   0   |   5   |   A
   1  |   0    |   3   |   0   |   5   |   A
   0  |   1    |   1   |  45   |  20   |   B
```

I'd like to reformat this table to show *per year* the *number of features* that fit certain criteria. The criteria are:

1. More than zero event occurrences for countries A+B;
2. More than 1 event occurrences for countries A+B;
3. More than zero event occurrences for country A.

so that the final table using the example above would looks like:

```
criterium | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 |
   1           1      2      3      1     3
   2           0      1      1      1     3
   3           1      1      2      0     2
```

and the table content of columns 2:6 would be the number of features of the original table, that meet the criterium *for that specific year*.

I've been toying around with the Statistics toolset, but so far without success. Any tips are welcome.

Edit: Opted for Q&D solution by exporting the attribute table to R and wrote a script to calculate the cell values.

Comment: Will your table only every have 2 countries?

Comment: Yes, the expected output is correct. Thanks for edit. As it is now, my data has 4 different countries, but I'm only interested in 2 options: country A or NOT country A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were me...

This could be done in a model but it would be a bit fiddly. I think this would be much easier to write in Python.

You would essentially query your data 3 times one for each criteria get a count and insert the count into a table.

So you need to be looking at the help file at how to use [`arcpy`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000v000000v7000000)'s [`SelectLayerByAttribute_management()`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000071000000), [`GetCount_management()`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000n7000000) and [`InsertCursor()`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v0000002z000000) (ArcGIS 10.0 or earlier) or [`da.InsertCursor()`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w0000000t000000) (ArcGIS 10.1+) functions to achieve this.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer. You're right that it's too cumbersome for a model. I've exported the Att. table to R and solved it there.